# Where clause on a property of a child object within a hasmany in fluent mapping

Tags: fluent-nhibernate, parent-child, has-many, fluent-nhibernate-mapping

I want to limit a list by a property that is on a child within a HasMany mapping.

I have a `Customer` object like so:

```
public class Customer
{
    public virtual int CustomerId { get; set; }
    public virtual IList<RecurringPayment> Recurring { get; set; }
}
```

and then my recurring

```
public class RecurringPayment
{
    public virtual int RecurringPaymentId{ get; set; }
    public virtual ItemBase OriginalItem { get; set; }
}
```

`ItemBase` has a type discriminator, but that isn't relevant.  Here's the part that is:

```
public class ItemBase
{
    public virtual int ItemId { get; set; }
    public virtual ItemStatus Status { get; set; }
}
```

`ItemStatus` is an enum

So, let's look at the mappings backwards.  First the item

```
public sealed class ItemBaseMap : ClassMap<ItemBase>
{
    public ItemBaseMap()
    {
        //omit the non-important parts

        Map(x => x.Status, "Status").CustomType<ItemStatus>();
    }
}
```

and now, the recurring payment

```
public sealed class RecrringPaymentMap: ClassMap<RecurringPayment>
{
    public RecrringPaymentMap()
    {
        //omit the non-important parts

        References<ItemBase>(x => x.OriginalItem, "OriginalItemId");
    }
}
```

and finally, my customer mapping.

```
public sealed class CustomerMap: ClassMap<Customer>
{
    public CustomerMap()
    {
        //omit the non-important parts

        HasMany<RecurringPayment>(x => x.Recurring)
                .KeyColumn("CustomerId")
                .Where("OriginalItem.Status != 6")
                .Inverse()
                .Fetch.Subselect();
    }
}
```

My problem comes with the where clause on the `HasMany` in my customer mapping.  If I do above with the string where clause. I get an error:

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException : The multi-part identifier "OriginalItem.Status" could not be bound.

If I switch it and do my where clause with linq as `.Where(y => y.OriginalItem.Status != ItemStatus.Deleted)` I get a different error:

> System.InvalidOperationException : variable 'y' of type 'Namespace.RecurringPayment' referenced from scope '', but it is not defined

So, how do I limit my list of recurring payments to only those where the original item is not deleted (Status 6)?

Comment: I'm seeing the same thing, with the LINQ implementation.  Any luck?

Comment: No luck with figuring this one out.  I just left the mapping without the where clause and then I filter out deleted items and their recurring payments in a separate linq statement before using the non-deleted recurring.